# Making Windows Context Menu to call a funtion C#

Tags: c#, contextmenu

In the program, I would like to add an item to the windows context menu only when the program is running;

Therefor, it would have to be added when the program runs and removed when the program exits. Also instead of running an .exe file when clicked on I would like to make it so it calls a method inside of my program.

Is the second part possible, and if so do you have any information on it?

Comment: Not sure if possible. Is it an option, if it sends parameters to the standard input of the already opened program (process)? Therefor the program will invoke whichever method is needed based on the recieved input

Comment: You can modify/unmodify the registry to include the command when the program runs or exits (will have to run with Admin privileges), that part isn't too difficult. Commands need to start programs with arguments though, so you could have a stub executable take an argument and use some kind of IPC to call a method in the main executable.

Comment: I think you'd probably have to implement this as two separate pieces - one is your program that exposes some kind of endpoint, and the other would be a shell extension that, among other things, implements [`IContextMenu`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776095(v=vs.85).aspx). It would then decide whether to show an item or not based on whether it can access the running program's endpoint. The shell extension probably won't be written in C# though.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going the route Ron Beyer suggested and made a separate program that sends a message to the main program through named pipes. Thanks for all the suggestions.